# Building a dataframe on the fly

Tags: python, dataframe

This is a question about how to make building a Pandas.DataFrame more elegant / succinct.
I want to create a dataframe from a list of tuples. 
I can go as usual and create it from the list after collecting all of them, for example,

```
import pandas as pd
L = []
for d in mydata:
    a,b,c = food(d)
    L.append(a,b,c)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=L,columns=['A','B','C'])
```

However, I would like instead to immediately add the rows to the dataframe, instead of keeping the intermediate list, hence using  dataframes as the sole datastructure in my code.

This seems much more elegant to me; one possible way to do this is to indeed use DataFrame's append function, as suggested by @PejoPhylo:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A','B','C'])
for d in mydata:
    a,b,c = food(d)
    df.append([(a,b,c)])
```

However, If I do this, it creates additional columns, named 1,2,3, etc.
I could also add a dictionary in each row:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A','B','C'])
for d in mydata:
    a,b,c = food(d)
    df.append([{'A':a,'B':b,'C':c)])
```

But I would still like some way to add the data without specifying the names of the columns at each iteration.

Is there a way to do this which will be as efficient as the uppermost version of the code yes not seem cumbersome?

Comment: Have you checked out the pandas.DataFrame.append function?

Comment: @PejoPhylo , This doesnt solve my issue: if I do this then I either have to add the new row as a series/dict for the columns to be consistent. This is quite combersome. If I instead use e.g, a list of tuples as the argument of append then new columns with default names are created. It would be nice if the default behavior was to use the already existing columns if the number of added values match.

Comment: I'm not sure whether i fully understand the problem. Could you edit your answer to illustrate where the problem lies?

Comment: My first thought is to play around with `df = pd.DataFrame(list(map(food, mydata)))` kind of structures. But as I have no reproducible example, it remains very silly speculation that any variant of this method would even get near the required results. :)

Comment: That could actually work but I'm not sure I want to put everything inside my loop into a single function, so its limiting.

Comment: Is `len(mydata)` available at the start?

Comment: Let's assume it is, what if so?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be the accepted way to do it, as the question stated:

```
import pandas as pd
L = []
for d in mydata:
    a,b,c = food(d)
    L.append((a,b,c))
df = pd.DataFrame(data=L,columns=['A','B','C'])
```

DataFrame.append is deprecated.